# Style a class within another class if it is preceded by a div with a special class inside

Tags: css

I want to edit css style for a `Class3` which is inside a `Class2` right after a `Class1`.

but I only want to edit style if Class1 has a `specialClass` inside, like this:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="specialClass"></div>
</div>
<div class="class2">
    <span class="class3"></span>
</div>
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
.class1 .specialClass ~ .class2 .class3 {}
```

Is this even possible? If yes can someone explain me the error I made?

Comment: Maybe we can be of better help if you also include your endgame in this scenario. There may be a simpler solution that doesn’t involve complicated (and impossible, to my knowledge) css.

Comment: Ben Steward, the fact is that i am not able to modify html

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: yes, i guess i could use js

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that may be the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 if($('.class1').find('.specialClass').length > 0){
     $('.class3').css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span{
  padding-left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="specialClass"></div>
</div>
<div class="class2">
    <span class="class3"></span>
</div>
```